# How to receive data (CAN bus messages from an application on PC) via TCP into a Web Server running on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, tcp, webserver, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I want to receive data into a local web server that I have created using Raspberry Pi. It is not connected to the internet. I want to know if it is possible to receive data from an application on a Windows PC that sends via TCP protocol. The web server is an Apache server. I can specify the web server address and port number in the application that sends the data.

I am a newbee to this and I just know what tcp, http etc means. I do not know them in detail so I am finding it hard to understand related articles on the internet. Can someone please help me with some code snippets on how to set the web server in raspberry pi so that I can receive the data? Either display it on the web server page or extract the data somewhere using Python or C#. I am also open to using a Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT image instead of Jessie to do the same.

Comment: `HTTP` = `Hyper Text Transfer Protocol`. It means all data (sends by TCP) will have special headers with HTTP informations (who sends data, who have to receive data, what type of data are send - HTML, image, JSON, etc). Web server can receive data by TCP only if sender use HTTP.

Comment: I guess it sends via HTTP. If that was the case then how do you think I can proceed?

Comment: Everything is possible ;) But seriously. If data send over tcp is simple http post/get data, then taka a look into Python Tornado. You will be able to quickly setup web server in python and in the same python script do some data processing. If it's some pure data packets you can use python scapy to disassemble data from single tcp packets. If you don't have full knowledge how data looks like, you can use Wireshark on your laptop to do some reverse engineering. You provide to less information to give you more strict answer.

Comment: @maQ Thanks.. I know it is pretty less information. Its just that the idea is vague in my head as well. But, I will try to check the data using Wireshark. That could be a good start. I can give some more details then.

Comment: What is sending the data? An application, a hardware device, etc? What format is it sending data in?

Comment: @halfer As mentioned in my main post, an application(in my Windows PC) is sending some data via TCP protocol. It uses HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

With Windows IoT you can start with [Hello blinky](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloblinkyserver) sample that create a simple Web Server in Python.

Also, [restup](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup) create a Web server in C# you can reference. This is the tutorial help you set up the code lines. I test TCP packets receiving on Raspberry Pi 3 with this web server, it works.

Hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Are you able to view the data received from the TCP packets?

Comment: Yes, `streamData` in `ParseRequestStream()` of `HttpRequestParser.cs` is the data what you send.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will try to implement this. Since I am new to this, it will take some time to understand what to do with the restup project. I hope I can figure it out. Thankyou.